# Eleventy permalink output conflict when more than 2 pages added to collection

Tags: permalinks, eleventy

I'm having the strangest issue with permalinks and could use some help.

- Windows 11
- Eleventy 2.0.1
- Nunjucks engine

Repo: https://github.com/wcDogg/eleventy-test

- `npm run build` - No errors
- Move `test-c.md` to either `/c_blog/` or `/c_docs/`
- `npm run build` - Output conflict

I discovered this in a larger project and reproduced it in the repo above:

- There 2 collections defined in `.eleventy.js` - `blog` and `docs`.
- Each collection has it's own a directory - `c_blog` and `c_docs`.
- Each directory has a JSON with a default permalink like this: `"permalink": "/blog/{{ page.fileSlug }}/"`.
- Each directory has an `index.html` where the default is overridden like this: `permalink: /blog/`.

This works as expected for the `index.html`, `test-a.md`, and `test-b.md`. However, once a `test-c.md` is added to either collection, I get this:

```bash
[11ty] Output conflict: multiple input files are writing to `public/blog/index.html`. Use distinct `permalink` values to resolve this conflict.
[11ty]   1. ./src/c_blog/index.html
[11ty]   2. ./src/c_blog/index.html (via DuplicatePermalinkOutputError)
```

I'm not sure what's going on or how to investigate further - any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue happens when using pagination.

In my case, I had `size: 2`. After the second post, there is a `/blog/1/index.html` that the permalink doesn't account for. Solution is to use:

```yaml
permalink: "/blog{% if pagination.pageNumber > 0 %}/{{ pagination.pageNumber }}{% endif %}/index.html"
```

Many thanks to the Eleventy Discord community for this :)